# Trying to set up Angular application for the first time

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am having issues trying to get an angular framework setup to start a new project, and having some challenges. I installed node.js and as you can see I have v14.17.1 installed. when I try the command npm -g @angular/cli i get some errors that I don't know how to fix. Not sure what my next steps should be to help get this working. thanks.

> C:\Users***\Documents\Codding\Angular>node -v v14.17.1
>
> C:\Users***\Documents\Codding\Angular>npm -g @angular/cli npm ERR!
> code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path
> C:\Users***\Documents\Codding\Angular/package.json npm ERR! errno
> -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users***\Documents\Codding\Angular\package.json' npm ERR! enoent
> This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users***\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-23T11_15_18_924Z-debug.log

[cmd promt errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKyTO.png)

Comment: is `npm install -g @angular/cli`, (you forgot the "install") see the docs:https://angular.io/cli, after you create a new Angular using `ng new my-first-project`

Comment: `npm install -g [module]` means, install the module to my global npm modules library so it can be used in any project. In your case, the `[module]` is `@angular/cli`. As Eliseo pointed out, you forget the `install` keyword and so you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have left out the "install" part of the npm command.

Try

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then, once that finishes, you can verify by running

```
ng version
```